# remove the data including serached patterns to the end block of pattern python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a output file which has three status codes as `SUCCESS` , `UNREACHABLE` and `FAILED`, what i'm looking is to first serach these two codes `UNREACHABLE` and `FAILED`, i need the data to be removed including the pattern line upto the end block `}`  as soon it get the line searched for these patterns.

Below is the data file `data.txt`

```
host8 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "[Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on 192.144.16.229",
    "unreachable": true
}

host4 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
; generated by kdns-config-net
domain sammer.com
search sammer.com
nameserver 192.168.1.10
nameserver 192.168.1.11
nameserver 192.168.1.12

host1 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "",
    "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: /grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.10/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
    "rc": 0
}
```

Below is Just  icreated the serached pattern but looking fort the ideas to remove the data as described above!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# data_parse.py
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    if "FAILED" in line or "UNREACHABLE" in line:
        print(line)
f.close()
```

Test result of the script is as follows:

```
host1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
host2 | UNREACHABLE! => {
host3 | FAILED! => {
host4 | FAILED! => {
```

Desired Data:

```
host4 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
; generated by kdns-config-net
domain sammer.com
search sammer.com
nameserver 192.168.1.10
nameserver 192.168.1.11
nameserver 192.168.1.12
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the desired output for the sample input.

Comment: @ScottHunter, I have updated the POST, though i need only data which is starting with `SUCCESS` in line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes some assumptions about what can appear in the other data, but you haven't provided the information necessary to tell if they are valid or not.

```
inSuccess = False
for line in f:
    if inSuccess:
        if "FAILED" in line or "UNREACHABLE" in line:
            inSuccess = False
        else:
            print(line)
    elif "| SUCCESS |" in line:
        inSuccess = True
        print(line)
```

Comment: thnx let me try.

Comment: Scoot, Do we need second `print` statement? becaue here `else` condition will suffice to cover the pattern if the pattern is not in `if` condition.

Comment: If you asking if you need the second `print` at all, then yes: otherwise, the SUCCESS line won't get printed (unless it immediately follows a SUCCESS section)

Comment: If you are asking if the explicit test for SUCCESS is needed, and can't be replaced with an else, then also yes: otherwise, data lines not in a SUCCESS section would be treated as SUCCESS lines.

Comment: Brilliant @Scott